# Objective-C block as return type

Tags: objective-c, block, anonymous

When I check out the src of [Underscore](https://github.com/robb/Underscore.m) project, then I found that the block somehow comprehensive for me:

```
typedef BOOL (^UnderscoreTestBlock)(id obj);
```

In the class, it define this class method:

```
+ (UnderscoreTestBlock (^)(UnderscoreTestBlock))negate
{
    return ^UnderscoreTestBlock (UnderscoreTestBlock test) {
        return ^BOOL (id obj) {
            return !test(obj);
        };
    };
}
```

and how can I understand these code, Thanks!

Comment: return an anonymous block that hold an UnderscoreTestBlock argument and return UnderscoreTestBlock block

am I wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that you got it right. `negate` is a class method which returns a block.
That returned block takes an `UnderscoreTestBlock` argument and returns another `UnderscoreTestBlock`. Example:

```
UnderscoreTestBlock isANumber = ^BOOL (id obj) {
    return [obj isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]];
};
BOOL b1 = isANumber(@123);       // YES
BOOL b2 = isANumber(@"abc");     // NO

UnderscoreTestBlock isNotANumber = [Underscore negate](isANumber);
BOOL b3 = isNotANumber(@123);   // NO
BOOL b4 = isNotANumber(@"abc"); // YES
```

`[Underscore negate]` returns a block that is called with the `isANumber` argument.
The return value of that call is the block

```
^BOOL (id obj) { return !test(obj); };
```

where `test` is the `isANumber` argument, which is *captured* by the block.

---

I am sure that there are good reasons why the Underscore project defines the `negate`
method like this, it is probably necessary for their "functional" notation.
Otherwise a slightly simpler way would be to define a method

```
+ (UnderscoreTestBlock)negateBlock:(UnderscoreTestBlock)test
{
    return ^BOOL (id obj) {
        return !test(obj);
    };
}
```

which would be used like

```
UnderscoreTestBlock isNotANumber = [Underscore negateBlock:isANumber];
```